# Data.php file function log()

Tags: helper, log

I am trying to understand following code (it is from Data.php). I am assuming it creates some sort of log file, but i can not figure out where can i find it. Can any one help me please? *(It does not create file erply.log - i have searched it from all the directories).*

```
class Eepohs_Erply_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data {
 private $_filename = 'erply.log';
 public function log($message, $method = null, $line = null) {
  if ( Mage::getStoreConfig('eepohs_erply/general/log_enabled') ) { 
   if ( is_null($method) ) $method = __METHOD__;
   if ( is_null($line) ) $line = __LINE__; Mage::log(sprintf('%s(%s): %s', $method, $line,
   print_r($message, true)), null, $this->_filename); 
  }
 }
}
```

All the files associated with it are located in https://github.com/erplyopensource/magento-integration *(i am just trying to understand the code)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to add some information here

First look at

```
Mage::log(sprintf('%s(%s): %s', $method, $line,  print_r($message, true)), null, $this->_filename)
```

As per as this code their are 3 parameters sended to log() function

- message
- level
- log file name

But in `Mage::log()` function there are `4 parameters on function`

```
public static function log($message, $level = null, $file = '', $forceLog = false)
    {
      ....
        try {
            $logActive = self::getStoreConfig('dev/log/active');
            if (empty($file)) {
                $file = self::getStoreConfig('dev/log/file');
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $logActive = true;
        }

        if (!self::$_isDeveloperMode && !$logActive && !$forceLog) {
            return;
        }
.......
      }
```

and 4th params is `forceLog`, which create log file forcefully 
even `Configuration->Developer->Log settings->Enabled` is No..

As you did not send `this parameter` that value `is set as false` to this and as you `disabled the log setting` that `it does not create log file`.So need to enable this setting.

if you want create log  which  `does not depends on log setting` then send 4th parameter as `true`  and also set a custog file name

```
Mage::log(sprintf('%s(%s): %s', $method, $line,  print_r($message, true)), null, 'custom.log',true)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Magento log uses `self::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'log'` as a directory to log to. This means it's in your Magento installation's folder in `var/log`.

In this case the filename is parsed as a 3rd argument: `erply.log`. So the path should be `var/log/erply.log`.

If you're not seeing any logs check the following

1. The `var/log` dir is writable (chmod 775 and the right owner)
2. `System > Configuration > Developer > Logsettings` has logging turned on

Answer (score 1):

**Solved:** Configuration->Developer->Log settings->Enabled: Yes

The file appears then in the var/log directory.